# Python Calculator for whole equation

Tags: python-3.x, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator in python but I am unable to figure out how to take whole equation as input and then solve like. (X+Y)*Z where x,y,z are numbers

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not here to do your homework for you, but if you've made an attempt and are having difficulties, we'd be happy to assist. But you should show your work first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use python's built-in function `eval`. eg. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval

```
>>> x = 1
>>> print eval('x+1')
2
```

Comment: No mater the question, the link should be `python 3` for the tag.

Comment: The function `eval` is not deprecated in python 3 https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

Comment: Thanx for the help